Grammatically, does 2 Samuel 7:15's אֲשֶׁ֥ר have to refer to Saul?
In 2 Samuel 7:15, there are two subordinate clauses.  Almost all translations have the first subordinate clause referring to God's favor, and the second referring to Saul, as in the NIV translation:

But my love will never be taken away from him, as I took it away from
Saul, whom I removed from before you.

My question is about the grammar of the second subordinate clause, which starts with אֲשֶׁ֥ר.  Does אֲשֶׁ֥ר have to refer to Saul?
The other obvious choice would be for the second subordinate clause to also be referring to God's favor.  I understand that from context, it would be strange at this point for God to be declaring the removal of His favor from David.  That's not my question.  My question is only about what is necessitated by the sentence structure.
For comparison, Jeremiah 8:2 has a series of subordinate clauses, but the list uses וַאֲשֶׁ֤ר , which includes a conjunctive.

They will spread them out to the sun, the moon, and to all the
heavenly [a]lights, which they have loved, which they have
served, which they have followed...

However, Micah 1:1 has two subordinate clauses in a series without a conjunctive.

The word of the Lord which came to Micah of Moresheth in the days
of Jotham, Ahaz, and Hezekiah, kings of Judah, and which he saw
regarding Samaria and Jerusalem.


Some of the facts quoted by the OP are not quite correct.  So, let me set out the linguistic facts of the three verses referenced by the OP (with my literal translations).

2 Sam 7:15 - But My loving devotion will never be removed from him as I removed it from Saul, whom I moved out of your way.

In this case the relative particle, אֲשֶׁר is alone and thus refers to the noun immediately preceding it - in this case, "Saul".

Jer 8:2 - They will spread them out to the sun, the moon, and all the host of heavens, which they have loved, and which they
have served, and which they have walked after, and which they have
sought, and which they have worshiped. They will not be gathered
nor buried; they will be like dung on the face of the ground.

Notice that the first אֲשֶׁ֨ר is just alone (no conjunction); but all the subsequent four have the conjunction "and" attached making a chain of subordinate clauses all referring back to, in this case, "the sun, the moon, and all the host of heavens".

Micah 1:1 - The word of YHWH that came to Micah the Moreshite in days of Jotham, Ahaz, Hezekiah, kings of Judah, which he saw;
regarding Samaria and Jerusalem.

There are two case to consider here:

"that" - notice the noun chain "word of YHWH" so word is construct state and YHWH is absolute state; therefore, אֲשֶׁ֣ר refers to "word of YHWH"
"which" refers to the previous noun chain again, namely, "kings of Judah".

In this last case, no conjunction is used and so they have different antecedents as listed above.  Thus, the last phrase, introduced by a preposition is distinct and refers back to the first part of the sentence.

For Micah 1:1, NIV has "the vision he saw", NLT has "visions he saw", BES has "what he saw regarding". Are you saying these are incorrect, or only not as likely the intended meaning?

@RayButterworth - the word "vision" is absent from the text - what Micah "saw" was the kings of Judah, Jotham, Ahaz, and Hezekiah.
